# Tensorflow2.0 reuse layers

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
def head(self, input, num_anchors, name, flatten=False):
    out_channels = (self.num_classes + 4) * num_anchors
    conv = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, 'same', activation='relu', name=name+'_conv1')(input)
    conv = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, 'same', activation='relu', name=name+'_conv2')(conv)
    conv = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, 1, 'same', activation='relu', name=name+'_conv3')(conv)
    out = layers.Conv2D(out_channels, 3, 1, 'same', name=name+'output')(conv)
    if flatten is True:
        batch_size = tf.shape(out)[0]
        out = tf.reshape(out, [batch_size, -1, num_anchors, self.num_classes+4])
        out = tf.reshape(out, [batch_size, -1, self.num_classes+4])
    return out
```

I want to know how to reuse these layers as tf.variable_scope(scope resue=tf.AUTO_REUSE) in tensorflow1

In tensorflow1

`with tf.variable_scope('', resue=tf.AUTO_REUSE) as scope:
         all layers here could be auto reuse`

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the layers by just having a common reference. I have attached a sample code below. I am making use of a variable named as `common_layer` which will be used in three separate models (sequential and functional). The first model is trained and after that we subtract the weights from `common_layer` of all the three models. It proves that what changes happen in first model's layer gets reflected in other model's common layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

common_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, name='common_layer')

model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((100)),
    common_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((100)),
    common_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input((100))
output_layer = common_layer(input_layer)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20)(output_layer)
model3 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output_layer])

model1.compile('adam', loss='mse')
model1.fit(np.random.rand(128, 100), np.random.rand(128, 1))

weights1 = model1.get_weights()[0]
weights2 = model2.get_weights()[0]
weights3 = model3.get_weights()[0]
print(np.sum(weights1 - weights2))  # 0.0
print(np.sum(weights1 - weights3))  # 0.0
```

Comment: If I don't use Sequential(), how to resue them, thanks

Comment: @xinruli I have added functional model also. Basically you just have to use a common reference.